# How to set Python console in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is my first question here. I just moved from Spyder to VS Code and in Spyder if I wanted to run my code I would just press F5 and it would run in the console, but in VS Code I need to press F5 then enter and wait a bit until the powershell runs the file and then see the output. Is there a way to make that faster?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it by setting a `shortcut` editing `keybindings.json` file. Pressing `ctrl + k + s` (if you haven't changed before) you can open it and then type `run python file in terminal`, then click on it and set the shortcut that you wanna press to run the current python file. I'm attaching an image to support the explanation.

[image]